# Error message from php executing c script

Tags: php, error-handling, segmentation-fault, exec

I spent hours trying to debug a php script which runs a c simulation using exec(). After throwing stderr print messages in everywhere, I finally found that the underlying issue was printing a directory path to a char array that was too small using sprintf().

I'm guessing it was a segmentation fault, but I never actually saw the shell error message saying 'segmentation fault'. When I changed the allocation size, everything worked.

I had been redirecting stderr output to a log file, and that log file got all of the messages from fprintf(stderr,"..."); but it didn't get any shell error messages.

The command is this

```
exec("$cmd 2>> $logFile & $PROCFILE 1 $ipaddr $! 2>> $logFile", $output, $rv);
```

$cmd runs a c simulation, and $PROCFILE runs a second c program that takes three arguments (the 1, $ipaddr, and $!). Before I fixed the allocation size problem, the php script would just stop execution of the $cmd simulation and continue on the next line (i.e. after the exec() statement). The next line in the php file is

```
if(rv!=0){handle error}
```

but that also didn't catch the problem.

I kept thinking I was running into a permissions error. How can one get exec() to show the shell errors? Or was this a result of running the two programs simultaneously with '&'?

Answer (score 0):

When a program dies, the "Segmentation fault" message comes from the shell, not from the program. Redirection only applies to the program's output, not the shell's. The message should get put into the $output variable. If $rv is 0 and there's nothing in $output, I suspect you're wrong about what happened. I suggest you verify this by writing a simple test program that just does:

```
kill(0, SIGSEGV);
```

BTW, why aren't you using `snprintf()`, so you can't get a buffer overflow in the first place?

Comment: wasn't using snprintf() because i'm stupid. i'm fairly certain the issue was printing beyond the boundary of the char array because doubling the allocation fixed the problem. i'm thinking $rv might not have been 0 because i was executing two commands simultaneously. do you mean try exec("kill(0,SIGSEGV)")?

Comment: No, I mean make the program in $cmd a simple program that just kills itself with a segmentation error.